# Lambda to function pointer adapter understanding

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

Bumped into some useful code for converting lambda taking some outer context to a function pointer and do not clearly understand some part of it.

What is the point to do this inheritance in the beginning of the code?

```
template<typename Lambda>
struct convert_lambda : convert_lambda<decltype(&Lambda::operator())> {};


template <typename Lambda, typename ReType, typename... Args>
struct convert_lambda<ReType(Lambda::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using  funPtr = ReType(*)(Args...);

    static funPtr make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
    {
        static const Lambda& lmda = t;
        return [](Args... args) { return lmda(args...); };
    }
};

template<typename Lambda>
using convert_lambda_t = typename convert_lambda<Lambda>::funPtr;

template<typename Lambda>
constexpr convert_lambda_t<Lambda> make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
{
    return convert_lambda<Lambda>::make_function_ptr(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inheritance is something similar to a deduction guideline (not quite the same). A Lambda has all the infos you need to declare your struct, but the constructor cannot infer the return type and arguments from the lambda (or maybe it could, but there is not a syntax for representing the signature of a lambda).

You can get the signature from `&Lambda::operator()` which is just a member function pointer to the call function of your lambda. Note that each lambda is basically a unnamed struct with a (normally `const`) `operator()`. From the type of the lambda, you already know everything about the implementation of the lambda.

Now `&Lambda::operator()` has the type `ReType(Lambda::*)(Args...) const`, where the `Lambda::*` denotes that it is member function pointer. So if you inherit from the type you actually want. Hence you don't need to write `convert_lambda<decltype(&Lambda::operator())>` when you want to use it.

You can get around this inheritance completely, by doing the following:

```cpp
template<typename Lambda>
struct convert_lambda; 

template <typename Lambda, typename ReType, typename... Args>
struct convert_lambda<ReType(Lambda::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using  funPtr = ReType(*)(Args...);

    static funPtr make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
    {
        static const Lambda& lmda = t;
        return [](Args... args) { return lmda(args...); };
    }
};

template<typename Lambda>
constexpr auto make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
{
    return convert_lambda<decltype(&Lambda::operator())>::make_function_ptr(t);
}
```

Since you probably will not use the `convert_lambda` at any other place, this should not be an incovenience.

To illustrate the similarity to deduction guides, I rewrote it using one (this needs C++17):

```cpp
template<typename Lambda>
struct convert_lambda; 

template <typename Lambda, typename ReType, typename... Args>
struct convert_lambda<ReType(Lambda::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using  funPtr = ReType(*)(Args...);

    convert_lambda(const Lambda& t) {}

    static funPtr make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
    {
        static const Lambda& lmda = t;
        return [](Args... args) { return lmda(args...); };
    }
};

template<typename Lambda>
convert_lambda(const Lambda& t) -> convert_lambda<decltype(&Lambda::operator())>;

template<typename Lambda>
constexpr auto make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
{
    return decltype(convert_lambda(t))::make_function_ptr(t);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in the style of ```std::underlying_type``` ? Where ```std::underlying_type<e1>``` exposes a member ```type``` that is the typedef you first thought of. I can't quite see how to get there.